# Commentary of Rash Sirilio on Zeraim

Tags: jewish-books, commentaries, mishna

Does anyone know where I can find the commentary of Rash Sirilio on Seder Zeraim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Wikipedia it says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_Talmud#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20first%20of,tractate%20Shekalim%20of%20Seder%20Moed.):

> One of the first of the Acharonim to write a commentary on the Jerusalem Talmud was Solomon Sirilio (1485–1554), also known as Rash Sirilio, whose commentaries cover only the Seder Zeraim and the tractate Shekalim of Seder Moed. Sirilio's commentary remained in manuscript form until 1875, when it was first printed in Mainz by Meir Lehmann.[17] In the Vilna edition of the Jerusalem Talmud, Rash Sirilio appears only for tractates Berakhot and Pe'ah **but the commentary for the entire Seder Zeraim appears in the Mutzal Mi’Eish edition of the Jerusalem Talmud.** In addition to his commentary, Sirilio worked to remove mistakes made by manuscript copyists that over time had slipped into the text of the Jerusalem Talmud and his amended text of the Gemara is reproduced alongside his commentary in the Vilna and Mutzal Mi’Eish editions of the Jerusalem Talmud.

These versions of the Yerushalmi are accessible on the Otzar website.
The links are as follows:
[Brachos](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=9831&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15992142316866852&pagenum=1)
[Peah](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=9836&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15992142316866852)
[Demai](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=155618&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15992142316866852)
[Kilayim](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=9609&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15992142316866852)
[Sheviis](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=26016&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15992142316866852)
[Terumos](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=9612&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15992142316866852)
[Maasros](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=13740&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15992142316866852)
[Maaser Sheini](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=155619&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15992142316866852)
[Challah](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=9850&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15992142316866852)
[Orla](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=151803&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15992142316866852)
[Bikurim](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=151804&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15992142316866852)

You can find the one for Sheviis fully downloadable [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/40726)